# Display file name next to file upload button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I would like to change position of file name next to kendo Upload button.

[image: Would like to set file name position in this way]

[This is reference link of code.](https://dojo.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change the template for the file list and probably change the drop zone.

Here is a demo where they change the template for the list.
[Template Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/templates).

Here is a demo where they use a custom drop zone:
[Custom Drop Zone](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/customdropzone)